# How to add alt-text with the R officer package?

Tags: r, accessibility, officer

I create powerpoint files using the R package Officer. I would like to make the files accessible by adding alt-text to each slide, and ideally to different parts of each slide. I know how to add alt-text using Rmarkdown when creating word documents, etc. but don't know if it is possible with Officer. I would like to use the Officer package because of the control it provides in placing content, etc.

Is it possible to add alt-text with Officer?

Comment: read the docs for you, no mention of it, also can't see anything in the few source files I read on GitHub so I would guess you will need to extend the package to include this yourself. Sadly I am no help to you there but hopefully someone else will know how you could do that!

Comment: no, it's not possible

Comment: OK, thanks. Having played with some powerpoint presentations and looked at the slide.xml files it looks like it just needs a "descr" attribute in the relevant content

<p:cNvPr id="5" name="Content Placeholder 4" descr="This is the alt text">
Now I need to figure out how to add that.